# Response a json type longitude and latitude using Google geocoding API in django using Python

Tags: python, json, django, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am a newcomer to Django programming.
 Here I am working on the server side.
 The thing I want to do is when client-side type a location in a string, the server will response a longitude and latitude using the geocoding API.
 But the problem is I can't even successfully import 'google maps' or 'django_google_maps' API in the visual studio
  How can I import them successfully and apply them to my server-side code?
 Thank you for answering

Comment: I can import them in cmd of python, but can't import in my views.py. And what's the relation between the 'django-google-maps' and the 'google maps'

Comment: Your intention is execute server side web service requests in Python, probably you can consider Python Client for Google Maps Services: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python